# Calling a method from an Angular app event

Tags: angularjs

Say I have this method:

```
function doThings() {
    //execute method
}
```

And I have some html similar to this:

```
<input type="button" value="Click Me" ng-click={{ doThings() }}/>
```

Would that correctly invoke the doThings() method? And where would I put the method declaration? In the controller, maybe? I'm new to AngularJS, so please be gentle :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty much the standard way the very basic angular app setup looks like with the `doThings()` function invoking. Working example:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.doThings = function() {
    alert('I do some things!');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <input type="button" value="Click Me" ng-click="doThings()" />
</div>
```

There is nice tutorial on w3schools: http://www.w3schools.com/angular/default.asp

Answer (score 0):

You have a named function with no implicit attachment to either `$scope` or a viewmodel variable in your controller, so that will *not* fire.

To make it fire, you would have to either bind it to `$scope`...

```
$scope.doThings = doThings;
```

...or define it to a VM variable and then invoke *that* in the view.

```
var vm = this;
vm.doThings = doThings;

// HTML
// assuming your controller is bound to vm through its directive
// or through ng-controller="Controller as vm"

<input type="button" value="Click Me" ng-click={{vm.doThings()}}>
```